# Export list to excel with filters?

Tags: list, permissions

I have a list with the setting that a user can only read/edit items they have created themselves which works fine, however, if they click Export to excel (which they should be able to) then all records gets exported - even the ones they don't have access to view in the list.

[Edit: added by OP]
I set a filter on the view to filter on items created by [Me].
Then I created a view that displays all items and in the ribbon I clicked on List Tools -> List and in the view drop down selected Configure Views for this location. I set the view for all items to be hidden from this location. If someone goes to that view by typing the URL in the browser they will still see the default view filtered on their user id. But, I gave the people I want to be able so see all items Manage List Permission on the list and put a link in a content editor web part on the filtered view with audience set on the admin group.

The admin group can see the link and go to the view with all items, if they export to excel they export all items.
A normal user can't see the link but even if they would figure out the URL they would still only see their own items, if the list is filtered on created by [me] then they can only export items created by themselves to excel.

How can I solve this without using custom code (not my decision)? Editing forms/views in SPD is fine.

Comment: A proposed solution would be creating new views, and applying filters to each view. For Example: Low Impact Items, High Impact Items, ...

If this is feasable ( you don't have to create many views ), then you will select the required view, and export it to Excel.

Comment: What version of SharePoint are you using?

Comment: So let me get this straight. You've setup the list settings so that users can only view their own items; but upon exporting to Excel, all items are transferred? That seems kind of odd and if it's really so, it's a bug imho. Could someone please test this (I don't have a working environment at the moment)?

Answer (score 1):

What I suppose you require is a modified version of this:

[Export selected items to Excel from a SharePoint list.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/400720/SharePoint-2010-Export-Selected-Items-to-Excel)

It also has a nice explanation of how this works.